# Paging with filtered users in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

When i paging all registered users in Asp.Net MVC i use:

"Membership.GetAllUsers(page ?? 0, pageSize, out totalUsers)"
method and it works fine. But also i want to filter users by role. So i use below code for filtering users by role. And it works fine.

```
                MembershipUserCollection allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
                MembershipUserCollection filteredUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();
                string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole(roleName);
                foreach (MembershipUser user in allUsers)
                {
                    foreach (string userInRole in usersInRole)
                    {
                        if (userInRole == user.UserName)
                        {
                            filteredUsers.Add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And my question is, How possible paging with filteredUsers? Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `.Skip` and `.Take` methods:

```
page = page ?? 0;
var filteredAndPaginatedUsers = filteredUsers
    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToArray();
```

Might not be very efficient because we are doing the paging and the filtering on the client side but I am afraid that the Membership API doesn't allow you to do paging and filtering at the same time.